Pandas DataFrame - find if row matches all values in dictionary
I'm doing an analysis along a pipeline, modeling points along segments, with some physical parameters.  I need to keep track of the progress so, when the model hangs due to connectivity issues, etc., I can pick back up without starting from scratch.
I'm storing the completed parameters in a dictionary, building into a list and storing to a CSV. At the start of the script, I'm pulling in all of the completed runs so far.
my current implementation will not scale well, as I'm converting the completed runs dataframe values to a list of runs and then comparing that to a list of the header values to see if any rows match.  I'm looking for a solution that will better scale.
# at the top of the script, pull in the runs completed to date
completed_runs_df = pd.read_csv('completed_runs.csv')
completed_runs_list_of_values = completed_runs.values
completed_runs_list_of_dicts = completed_runs.to_dict(orient='records')

for model in models:
    header = {
        'lat': lat,
        'long': long,
        'press_psig': press_psig,
        'diam_in': diam_in,
    }
    
    # need a better way to check this
    header_vals = list(header.values())
    if header_vals in completed_runs_list_of_values:
        continue
    
    # modeling goes here

    completed_runs_list_of_dicts.append(header)
    
    completed_runs_df = pd.DataFrame(completed_runs_list_of_dicts)
    completed_runs_df.to_csv('completed_runs.csv', index=False)

I'm looking for a direct method to take the header dictionary and immediately test if there is a matching row of values in completed_runs_df.

From your question it is difficult to understand exactly what you are looking for but my first thought would be to take one of two approaches: First: load data into a pandas dataframe and sort on Lat, Lon then by filtering the frame you can reduce the rows needed to be searched.  Second: create a nested dictionary of the form {lat1_value: {lon1_value: {psig_val, dia_val]}}

Can you create a geodataframe, and store the progress in the csv file as distances along the line

To improve the scalability of your solution, you can leverage the power of Pandas for efficient row checking and avoid converting the DataFrame to lists of values or dictionaries:
# Create a set of tuples representing the completed runs
completed_runs_set = set(tuple(row) for row in completed_runs_df.to_records(index=False))

new_runs = []

# Iterate through the models
for model in models:
    header = {
        'lat': lat,
        'long': long,
        'press_psig': press_psig,
        'diam_in': diam_in,
    }
    
    # Convert header to a tuple
    header_tuple = tuple(header.values())
    
    # Check if the header tuple is already in the completed runs set
    if header_tuple in completed_runs_set:
        continue
    
    ###### Modeling goes here ######

    # Append the header dictionary to new_runs list
    new_runs.append(header)

# Update the DataFrame and CSV file if there are new runs
if new_runs:
    new_runs_df = pd.DataFrame(new_runs)
    updated_runs_df = pd.concat([completed_runs_df, new_runs_df], ignore_index=True)

